# How can I find out how many of each letter is in a given string?

Tags: javascript

So I want my code to count the amount of times a letter shows up within a string and output the result.

ie:

```
amount(door, o) ===> 2
```

Can I do it using a for loop using

```js
function(amount,letter){
  var  count=0
  for (var i=0 ; i < amount.length ; i++) {
    if(amount[i] == letter[i]) count++
    }
  }
```

not really sure how to make it work

Comment: Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). [Rubber Duck Debug](//rubberduckdebugging.com/) your code. Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). What do you think does `letter[i]` mean? Which index of the single letter are you reading?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into an array, then loop through each of the letters. We have a letterTracker object, which is where our values are stored. If the key of the letter doesn't exist in the object already, we'll add the key to it. If it does exist, we'll just add one to it.

```
var countLetters = (string)=>{
    const stringArr = string.split('')
    let letterTracker = {};
    stringArr.forEach(letter=>{
        letterTracker[letter]
            ? letterTracker[letter]++
            : letterTracker[letter] = 1
    });
    return letterTracker;
}

countLetters('wuddup'); //returns { w: 1, u: 2, d: 2, p: 1 }
```

Using a more ES5 friendly method, and without splitting the string into an array, we can do this (the same result will be achieved):

```
function countLetters(string){
    let letterTracker = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        if(letterTracker[string[i]]){
            letterTracker[string[i]]++
        } else {
            letterTracker[string[i]] = 1
        }
    }
    return letterTracker;
}

countLetters('wuddupp?'); //returns { w: 1, u: 2, d: 2, p: 2, ?: 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was almost correct but there some mistakes

- You have to give the function a name
- You have to return `count`
- You have to pass actual strings
- You should use `let` or `const` instead of `var`
- You should use `===` instead of `==`

```js
function amount(word, letter) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if(word[i] === letter) count++
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(amount('door', 'o'));
```

Using array methods you can simplify even more

```js
function amount(word, letter) {
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(word, (acc, el) => acc + (el === letter), 0);
}

console.log(amount('door', 'o'));
```